# It does not call function in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, fractions

I am making simple fraction calculator using python3. 
I can still put input for `choice`, however it does not call any function;add, subtract,divide and multiply. 
Did I miss something?
Thanks in advance!

```
from fractions import Fraction
class Thefraction():

    def add(a,b):
        print('The result is %s' % (a+b))
    def subtract(a,b):
        print('The result is %s' % (a-b))
    def divide(a,b):
        print('The result is %s' % (a*b))
    def multiply(a,b):
        print('The result is %s' % (a/b))

    if __name__=='__main__':
        try:
            a = Fraction(input('Please type first fraction '))
            b = Fraction(input('Please type second fraction '))
            choice = input('Please select one of these 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4.multiply ')
            if choice ==1:
                add(a,b)
            if choice==2:
                subtract(a,b)
            if choice==3:
                divide(a,b)
            if choice==4:
                multiply(a,b)

        except ValueError:
            print('No fraction')
```

Comment: Among other things, the problem is that in python3, "input" receives a string. You need to use `int(choice)` or compare it to "string" representations of the numbers `if choice == '1'`.  Also, your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block needs to be outside of the class definition. Then, to use the class' methods, prefix them with `TheFraction` (ex: `TheFraction.add(a,b)`

Comment: Thank you for advice! I am going to fix now

Answer (score 2):

When you type in something in your input it saves it as a string instead of integer. So you can change the if statements to: `choice =='1'` or use `choice =int(choice)`

example:

```
choice = input('Please select one of these 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4.multiply ')
        if choice == '1':
            add(a,b)
        if choice== '2':
            subtract(a,b)
        if choice== '3':
            divide(a,b)
        if choice== '4':
            multiply(a,b)
```

Or:

```
choice = input('Please select one of these 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4.multiply ')
choice = int(choice)
            if choice ==1:
                add(a,b)
            if choice ==2:
                subtract(a,b)
            if choice ==3:
                divide(a,b)
            if choice ==4:
                multiply(a,b)
```